# Android Chrome/Firefox - AJAX request to different subdomain net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: android, ajax, google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate

A login POST request on Android's Chrome or Firefox is giving net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE (unable to read response data). The request is made to another subdomain, and we have a wildcard SSL certificate installed properly.

The responding nginx server is updated to the newest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was due to that the server's SSL certificate file needed to have CA bundle certificate in it for mobile Chrome to qualify the certificate.